# Uncaught (in promise) undefined error with setInterval Chrome only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise

Console keeps throwing an `Uncaught (in promise) undefined` for my JS that has no direct implementation of promises. I have a slideshow using transition that will work through the first image and then breaks after an attempt to change to the next. After lots of console.log-ging, the error seems to be thrown once it its my setInterval block:

```
window.setInterval(function() { //error happens once this line is hit

    lastPos = pos;
    pos++;

    // Wrap to beginning if necessary.
    if (pos >= $bgs.length)
        pos = 0;

    // Swap top images.
    $bgs[lastPos].classList.remove('top');
    $bgs[pos].classList.add('visible');
    $bgs[pos].classList.add('top');


    // Hide last image after a short delay.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $bgs[lastPos].classList.remove('visible');
    }, settings.delay / 2);

}, settings.delay);
```

This error is only being thrown in the latest version of Chrome, seems to work just fine in every other browser that I have tried. I saw a thread on issues with setInterval and inactive tabs, but this is thrown almost immediately after rendering the page. My transitions are spotty due to this, but work smoothly in other browsers.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't the error have a stack trace?

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co? What is `settings`?

Comment: @Bergi nope, nothing that I am able find at least. And `settings` is basically set to 6000. I've tried playing with this value too and it doesnt fix anything.

Comment: @xTopShelfx Can you create a reproducible example (with the whole code?) The part you posted doesn't seem to use promises or throw an `undefined` exception anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi I have my site live that you are more than welcome to review. It is at http://brianbolnick.com.

Comment: I see it on stackoverflow as well on chrome:
Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Comment: @xTopShelfx Do you still see the error in incognito mode? Im 100% certain now its one of my extensions

Comment: Yeah that's the weird thing is that I have no explicit calls to Promise... unless there is something that is nested under that library that I am unaware of... @Zee it still isn't working in incognito and I've disabled all of my extensions.. it does seem to work on mobile though, so I am thinking it might be a chrome 54 bug?